# What axioms are needed to show that every vector space has a "coordinate system"?

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

It is a well-known theorem that the axiom of choice (AC) is equivalent to the statement that every vector space over any field has a basis. In this question I am interested in the following somewhat dual concept to that of a basis:

If $V$ is some vector space over a field $K$, we call a subset $S\subseteq V'$ of the dual space a *coordinate system* for $V$ if

1. $S$ separates points, i.e. for each $0\neq v\in V$ there is some $s\in S$ with $sv\neq 0$ and
2. $S$ is irredundant in that no proper subset of it also separates points.

(If this is known under a different name, please let me know.)

This notion is somewhat less well behaved than that of a basis, but still mimics some of its properties. For instance: A subset $B\subseteq V$ is a basis if and only if the natural map
$K^{\oplus B}\to V$ is an isomorphism (and also, linear independence and generation correspond to injectivity and surjectivity vice versa). Along these same lines, some subset $S\subseteq V'$ is a coordinate system for $V$ if and only if the natural map $V\to K^S$ is injective and "uses all the space" in that following this map with a projection to any $K^{S'}$ for a proper subset $S'$ is never injective.

Under ZFC, every vector space has a coordinate system - simply pick a basis $B$ and take all the projections $\pi_b$ that extract the coefficient of $b$ from a linear combination (in other words, the dual basis $B'$ of $B$). It is also clear that for finite dimensional $V$, every coordinate system arises in this way. But for larger spaces, these notions diverge. For instance, this procedure performed on the direct product $K^\mathbb{N}$ gives some uncountable family in its (huge) dual space. But we may also simply take the countably many coordinate projections and obtain a coordinate system that way. Neither family is a basis for $(K^{\mathbb{N}})'$ and we even see that there can be coordinate systems of different cardinality.

However, it can be extrapolated from this example that having a coordinate system is a more robust property than having a basis: In ZF, every vector $V$ space that has a basis $B$, also has a coordinate system (the dual basis). But we can also use this same basis to obtain a coordinate system on $V'$, simply by taking the family of point evaluations at $b\in B$ (in other words, the image of $B$ under the double dual map $j:V\mapsto V''$). Hence, since it is consistent with ZF that not every dual space of a space with a basis itself has a basis (for instance $K^\mathbb{N}$ as the dual space of $K^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$), there can be spaces without a basis that still have a coordinate system.

Which finally brings me to the question: What is the set-theoretic strength of the statement that every vector space has a coordinate system? Are there concrete spaces that (consistently) do not have any? Or also, is there maybe some concrete procedure that, from a coordinate system of $V'''$ (say) produces a basis of $V$? Thanks for any information on that matter.

Comment: It seems it is unknown whether or not the statement "for every vector space $V$ and every $v \in V$ there exists $\phi \in V'$ such that $\phi(v) \ne 0$" is equivalent to AC. See these answers, both authored by @AsafKaragila https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970194/existence-of-non-trivial-linear-functional-on-any-vector-space https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313464/relation-between-the-axiom-of-choice-and-a-the-existence-of-a-hyperplane-not-con

Comment: Interesting! If that weaker condition is a plausible equivalent it seems rather likely that my (at first glance much stronger) statement should be surely of the same strength as full AC.